# Why is the ndim value of the matrix different from the matrix_rank?

Tags: python, numpy

I declare a matrix as follows,

```
vector1 = np.array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 0)]);
```

`np.ndim(vector1)` shows 2 and `matrix_rank(vector1)` shows 3.

Why are they different?

Comment: The number of dimensions is not related to the rank. Not every two dimensional matrix has rank 2.

Answer (score 2):

`np.ndim` refers to the dimension of the matrix, so a vector with length N has dimension 1, a NxN matrix has dimension 2, a NxNxN "multidimensional matrix" has dimension 3.

`matrix_rank` relates to the mathematical rank, i.e. the number of vectors that are needed to generate the from the matrix spanned space.

Comment: What does "a matrix in R^2" mean?

Comment: @MarkDickinson What I wrote was wrong. I'm refering (wanted to refer) to common matrixes, often denoted by `M(R)_(n,n)` or similar. Is my new formulation clearer (and correct)? EDIT: Well I guess technically `M(R^2)_(n,n)` is a well defined space of matrixes that consists of pairs of numbers, but it's misleading in this context.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing two different properties of matrices.
The dimension and the rank.

The dimension is equal to the number of indices.
e.g. a scalar has the dimension  0, a vector has the dimension 1, a common 2D matrix, like the one you gave, has the dimension 2.

The rank of a matrix is equal to the number of independent columns.
In the example you gave, the rank is 3, because none of the columns can be written as a linear combination of the other two columns.